# map with function pointers

Tags: c++, dictionary, function-pointers

I got a function that returns a minimum value from a given vector as

```
    float minValue(vector<int> v){
      auto it = min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
      return *it;
    }
```

now I got a map like

```
map<std::string, function*>
{
  {"min", /* here I need to use the above function call*/},
  //similarly for other requirements too
  {""}
 }
```

How can I use a key to point to the function pointer map value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you declare `function` actually? Your map definition should look like

```
map<std::string, float (*)(vector<int> v)> fnMap {
    {"min", &minValue } ,
    {"", NULL } 
};
```

---

As for your comment

```
typedef float(*function)(vector<int>);

map<std::string, function> fnMap {
    {"min", &minValue } ,
    {"", NULL } 
};
```

`function*` will result in a pointer to a function pointer.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. I have used a typedef like typedef float(*function)(vector<int>);

Comment: @user3979554 I have adopted this in my answer.

Comment: but when I do that it is throwing an error c2440: cannot convert from initializer-list to map, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Switch on `-std=c++11`